# My computer indicates that my mouse is plugged?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, mouse

My computer indicates that my mouse is `plugged`.  What does this mean?

Comment: "Plugged in" means that it's attached which means it's working normally.

Comment: If you feel that there's a problem with your mouse's functionality, you will get better results here if you give us the error message in its entirety.

Answer (score 4):

It means you have mice on your PC, get a pest control right away